# Ansible Insert XML before regex expression

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep, ansible

Here is an example regex that works with javascript/python

```
<!--.*[\n\t].*LAST FILTER IN THE DEFINED CHAIN.*[\n\t].*-->
```

Against this document:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>filter-plugin-dispatcher-before-dispatch-error</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>location</param-name>
        <param-value>before-dispatch</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>dispatcher</param-name>
        <param-value>ERROR</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>OktaLoginFilter<`enter code here`/filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.atlassian.jira.authenticator.okta.OktaLoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OktaLoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<!-- =====================================================
     THIS MUST BE THE LAST FILTER IN THE DEFINED CHAIN
     ===================================================== -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>JiraLastFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraLastFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Now I need to figure out how to correctly insert a block of xml before the above pattern using ansible.

I have attempted using this module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html and the current attempts to the above have been using config

```
- name: Insert/Update XML surronded by cutsomer markers after the last </filter>
  blockinfile:
    path: "path to file "
    backup: true
    marker: "<!-- {mark} ANSIBLE SIGSCI MANAGED BLOCK -->"
    insertbefore: "(<!--.*[\n\t].*LAST FILTER IN THE DEFINED CHAIN.*[\n\t].*-->)"
    block: |
        <filter>
            <filter-name>sigSciFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>params</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>rpcTimeout</param-name>
                <param-value>500</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>params</param-name>
                <param-value>unix:/var/run/params</param-value>
            d</init-param>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>parms</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
  notify:
    - Restart Sigsci
```

However, this regex patten does not match anything in the document and instead inserts at the end of the document. I am not sure the flavor regex that is used in this module but the lineinfile module allows for python regex and I would imagine that would work if I was inserting a single line, but I am trying to insert a block of xml before the matching regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the wrong tool for the job, you can use `-z` to have `grep` split on null bytes rather than linefeeds. Effectively, it'll treat an entire XML file as a single line:

```
$ grep -zo '<!--.*LAST FILTER IN THE DEFINED CHAIN.*-->' yourfile
<!-- =====================================================
     THIS MUST BE THE LAST FILTER IN THE DEFINED CHAIN
     ===================================================== -->
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have gave the full picture, I have am attempting to use a ansible module to insert before that block but the regex expression accepted doesn't allow me to pass options. Also, for whatever reason doesn't use python regex. Attempting to use: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html to insert a block of xml before a regex pattern, like requested above. I have update the question above to include more context

Comment: It doesn't sound like your question relates to grep or bash at all...

Comment: Unless im not understanding grep correctly, a regex expression that works with grep for this scenario should be the same syntax that the ansible regex expression is accepting. Now if that assumption is wrong, I can reword the above request.

Comment: Grep's default dialect is Posix BRE. It's used in several traditional Unix tools but it's rare for other tools to use it. You should definitely double check that. `grep` also matches line by line so it cannot match multiline patterns by default

Comment: Thats what I suspected, sounds like I would need to find a module that support multiline regexp. Thank you